# rails 7.days to human readable string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this looks trivial but let say that in Ruby on Rails I have

```
document.expire_in = 7.days
```

how can I print human readable version of the expiry mesages ?

```
"Document will expire in #{document.expire_in}"
=> Document will expire in 7 days
```

maybe something that works with `I18n.t` or `I18n.l`

the only way this works is

7.days.inspect
   => "7 days"

is this the only way ??

I'm looking at [ActiveSupport::Duratio](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html)n and don't see an answer

thx

Comment: What is wrong with `7.days.inspect`?

Comment: inspect is kind of reserved for debugging, but if nothing else I'll just use it :)

Comment: yeah and also it would be nice to have something that (like I'm saying) can be translated  with I18n  so  En "7 days",  SVK "7 dni"  ... :)

Comment: If you always want to print your time difference in days, you can have a homemade solution where you count the days and then pass that to a I18n.t

Comment: Yeah agree, I just wanted to know if there is something already existing directly in Rails so I wont try to reinvent the wheel :) ..but thx anyway  for trying to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there is no built in solution in Rails for this. I decided to go with

```
7.days.inspect => "7 days"
```

and later on, when project will get translated I'll extend `ActiveSupport::Duration` with something meaningful that will translate these

however I recommend  to look at Robert`s comments to this question. I agree with the solution to hold value in database e.g.: "7 days" and from that do stuff. Like translate the unit value

```
document = Document.new
document.expire_in = "7 days"

document.translated_day
```

in Document model (or decorator)

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  #....

  def translated_day
    timeline = expire_in.split(' ')
    "#{timeline.first} #{I18n.t("timeline.${timeline.last}")}"
  end
  #..
end


#config/locales/svk.yml
svk:
  timeline:
    days: "dni"
```

Comment: `.minutes.inspect` and `.hours.inspect` produce a result in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your specific question but it seems to me that you would be better off setting the datetime that it expires and then leverage [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words).

If you're always going to simply say 7 days, then why not just write that as a hard-coded string?

Comment: yeah I agree that this is a good solution (+1 for that), however in my case I don't want to specify exact Date & Time. Imagine this as Document that needs to be verified, and when that document will be verified (that can happen next month) since then calculate 7.days; So I'm holding the `"7 days"` in database already, from that I'm parsing to `7.days`, So yes I can say e.g: `Document.last.expiery_string  #=> "7 days"` but if I'll introduce translation in future I want to say also `"7.dni"` (Slovak lang), "7 dagen" (DE lang) ...

Comment: If that's the case, I would suggest adding one column that would hold unit and the other, I would indicate unit size. Use translations based on the unit size and the number remains the same. I might not be understanding your use case exactly, but this would allow you to have 7 days or 1 month or whatever else. This of course falls down if you want 1 month and 4 days. That might not be an issue in your case. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that demonstrates an i18n solution using `ActiveSupport::Duration#parts`

```ruby
duration.parts.map { |unit, n| I18n.t unit, count: n, scope: 'duration' }.to_sentence
```

which can work with a localisation like:

```yaml
en:
  duration:
    years:
      one: "%{count} year"
      other: "%{count} years"
    months:
      one: "%{count} month"
      other: "%{count} months"
    weeks:
      one: "%{count} week"
      other: "%{count} weeks"
    days:
      one: "%{count} day"
      other: "%{count} days"
    hours:
      one: "%{count} hour"
      other: "%{count} hours"
    minutes:
      one: "%{count} minute"
      other: "%{count} minutes"
    seconds:
      one: "%{count} second"
      other: "%{count} seconds"
```